# Initial setup Antminer S7

Tags: miner-configuration, antminer

I have a worker on slush's pool, I have my BFGminer running (Pool 0 is hiding block contents unsure if that's important) and my Antminer S7, but I can't  seem to get it to see it as a device. It ask for a target which is a serial port to probe for mining devices but I'm unsure what it's asking.

Answer (score 1):

The Antminer S7 runs standalone. It has a micro-controler that runs CGminer, and a web interface where you can point it to any pool you want. You just need to figure out the IP address of the miner, then type it in a web browser. The default password is `root/root`, if my memory serves me well.

In any case, you should read [the manual](https://s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/shop-bitmain/download/Antminer%20S7%20user%20guide.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can download IPreporter from Bitmain's support site. 
Run IPreporter software, now go to the miner and on the back side of the miner next the LAN port there is a button push is for 1-2 seconds. Now you should have the IP address. Paste it in a web browser and put your pwd in. And you have access.